# Render User#show from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I first check in Application controller for `request.subdomain.present?`.

If there is a subdomain in the URL such as `superstar3000.cappedin.com` I want to render `User#show` BUT I don't want to `redirect_to user_path(user)` because the URL ends up being `superstar3000.cappedin.com/user/1`

I just want to be able to render User#show so the URL is simply `superstar3000.cappedin.com`.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: I ended up just checking in a ApplicationController before filter if there is a subdomain. I basically copied all the logic from User#show to a new method that I put in ApplicationController. I then call `render template: "users/show"` after all my instance variables are set up.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index` action:

```
def index
  if subdomain
    @user = User.find_by(params[:id]) # Or however you want to assign in
  end
end
```

In your `index.html.erb`, assuming you have that partial

```
<% if @user %>
  <%= render 'users/show, {user: @user} %>
<% end %>
```